# write previously unknown number of data in a line

Tags: python

I have a huge number of file, from which I want to extract data and write to a file. A sample input line is:

```
 species,subl,cmp=    1    6    1    s1,torque= 0.11616E-06-0.50264E-14
 species,subl,cmp=    2    6    1    s1,torque= 0.13407E-03 0.74778E-07
 species,subl,cmp=    3    6    1    s1,torque= 0.71246E-06 0.28390E-14
 species,subl,cmp=    3    6    3    s1,torque=-0.46230E-12 0.30428E-13
```

and a given file have few such lines, which I want to write in a line

the small script shows my intention.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
# import math
import os

rootdir = str(sys.argv[1])
outf = str(sys.argv[2])
s = []
with open(outf, 'w') as of1:
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            if file == "out-Dy-eos2":
                inf = subdir+'/'+file
                with open(inf, 'r') as inf1:
                    for line in inf1:
                        if "species,subl,cmp=" in line:
                            of1.write(line[-13:])
#                             s.append(line[-13:])
#    print(s)
```

Its giving each output in new line, as:

```
-0.50264E-14
0.74778E-07
0.28390E-14
```

and so on, that is, a new line for each entry.

I have also tried to append a list, which comes like(kindly dont bother about the number):

```
 [0.12775E-02\n', '-0.19777E-11\n', '-0.18810E-13\n']
```

from what, I assume, new line is in the input file itself.
So, the question is, how can I write those value in the same line? without line break?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [`.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)?

Comment: or simply `of1.write(line[-13:-1])`

Answer (score 1):

this is pretty straight forward, just use line.rstrip('\n') before writing to the file. this also gives you an opportunity to format it how you want. for example

```
if "species,subl,cmp=" in line:
    data = line[-13:].rstrip('\n')
    of1.write(data+" ")
```

would give you a file that looks like

```
-0.50264E-14 0.74778E-07 0.28390E-14
```